# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

**Хотелось есть (,)  и надо было идти в город к почтамту,  где меня уже,  может быть,  ждали ребята.**

Понятно, что "хотелось есть." и " надо было идти в город к почтамту" - это односоставные безличные предложения. В первом предложении роль сказуемого выполняет сочетание модального глагола с инфинитивом,во втором предложении - сочетание предикативного наречия с инфинитивом. Но нужна ли запятая? Сперва мне показалось, что нужна, так как можно легко вставить форму дательного падежа личного местоимения "я" - "мне". 
Как-то так:" Мне хотелось есть и мне надо было идти". Но потом я что-то засомневался.
Как же стоит писать?

Comment: Посмотрела в оригинале (это ведь "Понедельник..." Стругацких?) Там есть.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, тут случай "авторской пунктуации". Можно и поставить, но необязательно. Прямой синонимии, о которой говорит [[@виктор1799](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799) нет, но по смыслу предложения однородные  - "[Мне] хотелось ... и надо было...". Поэтому, руководствуясь если не буквой, то духом Розенталя, запятую можно не ставить. ИМХО.

Answer (score 0):

На этот вопрос дает ответ РозентальД.Э.: "Запятая не ставится между двумя безличными предложениями, имеющими синонимичные слова в составе сказуемых, например: "Нужно переписать работу и надо объяснить допущенные в ней ошибки".
Думаю, "хотелось" и "надо было" вполне синомичные слова в составе сказуемых

Comment: Очень какая-то сомнительная синонимия. У Розенталя - "надо" и "нужно", тут не поспоришь... А вот "хотелось" и "надо" - это уже нечто принципиально иное...

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, здесь есть ошибка в употреблении союза И. Я бы изменила предложение.

*Хотелось есть, но надо было идти в город к почтамту, где меня уже, может быть, ждали ребята.* Или: *И хотелось есть, и надо было идти в город к почтамту*...

Comment: Тогда становится неинтересно. Запятую нельзя не поставить.

Comment: А иначе все-таки ошибка. Правда, извините, не берусь сформулировать ее словами.

Comment: @Ларf, претензии - к А. и Б. Стругацким. Фраза, видимо, из "Понедельника".

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось есть (,) и надо было идти в город к почтамту, где меня уже, может быть, ждали ребята. Мне кажется, что первое и второе простые предложения  - самостоятельные безличные предложения с составными глагольными, причём неоднородными,  сказуемыми. Следовательно, запятая при сочинительной связи между ними нужна.

Answer (score -3):

Мне кажется, что эти предложения безличны лишь формально. По смыслу они всё-таки личные. Местоимение "мне" определённо подразумевается. В то время, как в примере Розенталя они именно безличные. Кто именно будет переписывать работу и объяснять ошибки, можно определить исключительно по контексту. Например, перед его примером можно сказать: "Этот диктант я, пожалуй, верну ученику."

**UPD:** Интуитивное чувство языка меня не подвело в том плане, что запятая нужна. Хотя и подвело в части обоснования. Настоящая причина того, почему запятая нужна состоит в том, что сказуемые в безличных предложениях не однородны. Второе сказуемое - наречное. На этот счёт в правилах есть специальная оговорка: в случае неоднородности сказуемых запятая ставится.

Comment: Грамматика воогбще-то вещь конкетная, категориями "мнеп кажется по смыслу" не оперирует.

Comment: Оперирует. Смысл сказанного играет существенную роль при грамматическом разборе.

Comment: "Грамматический разбор" и "грамматика" соотносятся примерно как водопроводчик и канализация.       
Однороность-неоднородность членов - в какой-то мере действительно завязана на сымсле (о чем я и сказал), но тип предложения - вопрос чито грамматический и формальный. Никаких разговоров "по смыслу" не приемлет.

Comment: Вы слишком категоричны. Видимо, у вас в рукаве есть подтверждающий источник. Будьте любезны, предъявите его.

Comment: Источник - грамматика русскогоя зыка.
Shamov, не занимайтесь ерундой. На какой тезис вы хотите получить источник? Про водопроводчика? Это личное мнение. остально надлежит аргументировать, ибо вы этих тезисов накидали, а не мне доказывать, что я не верблюд.

Comment: Желательно на все тезисы последовательно. Про то, что грамматический разбор слабо связан с грамматикой. Если это так, то ещё и про то, что тип предложения - это грамматический вопрос. Ну, и про то, что грамматические вопросы исключительно формальны и не имеют отношения к смыслу.

Comment: ~1. "грамматический разбор слабо связан с грамматикой" - не ко мне. Я говорил, что это разные вещи. Грамматика (предложения) - объект изучения, разбор - метод. надеюсь, против этого вы не возражаете.
~2. "тип предложения - это грамматический вопрос". Это вытекает из определения грамматики как объекта изучения. Грамматика как наука изучает грамматику как объект. Ничего криминального.

Comment: ~3. "грамматические вопросы исключительно формальны и не имеют отношения к смыслу" - тоже ваши тараканы. Формальны описания грамматик, т.е. грубо говоря та модель, по которой мы грамматику изучаем. Но я не об этом. Я говорил, что классификация типа предложения - вопрос флрмальный. В том смысле, что определения не содержат никаких возможностей для манипуляций со смыслом или чего ещё там. Есть подлежащее и сказуемое - один тип, нет - дркгой. и т.д. Никаких лазеек.

Comment: shamov, я понимаю, что вам делать нечего, но ссылки все-таки просят в тех случаях, когда высказываются далеко не самочевидные вещи, с которыми можно и нужно спорить, я не тогда по сути сказать нечего.

Comment: Очевидно, в данном случае речь идёт о далеко не очевидных вещах, поскольку вы понимаете всё неправильно. Я имею в виду то, как резко вы разграничиваете грамматику и грамматический разбор. Вот я и подумал, что проблема не в вас, а в том источнике, которым вы вдохновляетесь.